Migrate projects and information from QGIS 2.x to QGIS 3.x
How can I migrate projects and information from QGIS 2.x to QGIS 3.x?
I can't find much documentation about it, it is from the QGIS version 2.18 to the current 3.34
What things must be taken into account?

Have you tried loading projects created in QGIS 2.x into QGIS 3.x? Does it refuse to do it?

Can you give more details about your project? Is it only maps with layers and print layouts? Or is it something more advanced with python scripts and so on?

QGIS is forwards compatible. So older projects can be opened in newer version of QGIS.
But if you have older project that you think need to be maintained, it might be prudent to open them in QGIS 3 and re-save them. As QGIS 2 to 3 definitely works, but QGIS 2 to 4 may be less so.
